# Unable to boot ubuntu mate

Tags: ubuntu

I get the following error:

```
Kernel panic-not syncing: 
VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,2)
```

here is the output of fdisk on the sd card:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 59.5 GiB, 63864569856 bytes, 124735488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x580a66ff

Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *      2048   133119   131072   64M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      133120 15728639 15595520  7.4G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52166/discussion-on-question-by-daveyman123-unable-to-boot-ubuntu-mate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to goldilocks!
I was able to solve this problem by using a smaller sd card and making sure there were no errors from dd when i installed.

I also used gparted to delete and format the sd card before doin dd.